# Cannot see js in mvc page using Firebug

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, html-select

I have a separate js file where I put my js. I can't even get into the js to debug it to see what the problem is.

**Firebug prior to this page has inline js I can see (from my master page (_Layout.cshtml).**

Once I get into this page, I get this from Firebug:

> No Javascript on this page
>   If  tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).

I don't know what I'm missing to simply fill this dropdownlist.....

Here is my new js file with the contents:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetCategories();
});

function GetCategories() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Index/Category",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var listItems = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                listItems += "<option value='" + data.CategoryID + "'>" + data.Description + "</option>";
            }
            $("#Categories").html(listItems);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the content of the html page. Note that my html is in my masterpage. So, I just need a simple script here...

```
<div title="JSON callback for dropdownlist">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Categories">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/JSON_DDL.js"></script>
```

Here is my result:

> [{"CategoryID":1,"Description":"ECommerce","Projects":[]},{"CategoryID":2,"Description":"Medical","Projects":[]}]

Comment: You sure it just can't find the path? Try a path to the script that is absolute from the base of the site.. eg, src="/Scripts/...."

Comment: Simon, I changed the path to <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/JSON_DDL.js"></script> and still got the same result... This is frustrating. All I'm trying to do is populate a ddl from JSON and as noted you can see the results coming back into the web page. However, it doesn't go into the Categories select list and no js appears on the page. I don't know what else to do :(

Comment: I have even taken the content of the html page (as you see above - with the <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/JSON_DDL.js"></script> in the _Layout.cshtml file. I started up the project, enabled Firebug, finally saw the inline script. I actually saw an empty ddl on the masterpage. I tried to set a breakpoint in the js at the "success" spot and Firebug informed me that the variable "data" was undefined. Isn't this where the data from the JSON call automatically comes back into? Note that I changed my url around where the Controller is first, then the Action method.

Comment: On my masterpage, I've changed it to an inline script and when the masterpage is loaded, I hit a breakpoint at GetCategories. However, I changed the word "data" to "result" in the success function and firebug still informs me that "result is undefined". It never gets into the Success function because of that. According to everything I've read, this syntax should be perfectly fine. I would appreciate help on this from anybody....

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your controller and confirmed that it is 1) being hit 2) serializing the returned data properly?

Comment: Don't know if below is the proper way to serialize it, but the breakpoint is being hit. If I debug the "categoryList" object after return from the db, you can see the 2 values inside there. The basic code of my Controler is the following: public JsonResult Index()    |

IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = db.GetCategories();    |

return Json(categoryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Actually, my Controller is not being hit at all! The code in the previous comment is the basicas of the Index JsonResult of my Category controller. Since I have the inline script inside my masterpage, the breakpoints of the above coded scripts are hit right away when the website comes up and starts to display the Home page. However, isnt't the url: 'Category\Index' in the GetCategories Ajax function supposed to hit my Controller? That's why the result is undefined. What do I need to do to make it hit my controller method? I'm running from http://localhost:9456/

Comment: Since I have the inline script inside my masterpage, the breakpoints of the above coded scripts are hit right away when the website comes up and starts to display the Home page. Once it executes the Ajax, it should populate my dropdownlist (on my masterpage - which it doesn't), then move on to my Home page, which it does.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problems in the past with Firebug.

One course of action is that Firebug has crashed and is not reading properly, close and reopen the brower. It's not as common a problem as it used to be, but it does happen.

The second problem took me a long time to find when it happened to me... and it sent me crazy for a couple of hours - but the solution was very simple - sometimes if your JavaScript syntax is bad (e.g. missing a closing curly brace) it won't be read and the browser won't even display an error. Double check your code carefully.

Comment: I tried both... No luck... I unchecked the box that says to disable script errors for other browsers. I'm using Firefox. I got the same result....